# This app is incompatible with all of your devices on setting min sdk version to 21

Tags: android, publishing

I have published my app with minimum SDK Version `21. Because I have used Camera2 in my project. I successfully published in playstore. but  it is showing **This app is incompatible with all of your devices.**.  Evn my mobile is marshmallow. it is also not displaying that application.

I have used below code in manifest file

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
```

please some one get me the solution.

Comment: post here your androidmanifest.xml.  Have you used any uses-features ?

Comment: @RujulGandhi I have updated my question. Pls check it

Comment: so your device doesn't have GLES features. so you are getting this error. if you still want to install that application then you can check my given answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have used any `uses-feature (AndroidManifest.xml)` then you have to set required as false as you can see below

```
<uses-feature
 android:name="android.hardware.camera"
 android:required="false" />
```

Because if you don't have that feature on device than you can see **This app is incompatible with all of your devices.**.

**The default value for android:required if not declared is "true". So you have to add one properties to camera2 and autofocus as false.**

please replace your code with below

```
<uses-feature 
    android:name="android.hardware.camera2" 
    android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature 
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" 
    android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="false" />
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: can I use that or I have to change it to Camera2?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168129/discussion-between-rujul-gandhi-and-basha).